# Nested Model Form. Belongs_to class not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Subject Model and a Lesson Model.
I implemented a nested model form.

After subject creation, I led it to a page where it supposedly shows the lessons associated. However, I fail to see the lessons.

I believe the data for lessons did not get saved properly as 
When I did a for example lesson.find_by_subject_id('1'), I get 'nil' in return.

I am trying to figure out how polymorphism works on rails and would appreciate it if someone could either point out where I've gone wrong or give me some guidance on how those to pass the values for belong_to classes to be created.

Subject Model

```
attr_accessible :subjectCode, :lessons_attributes
has_many :lessons, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Lesson Model

```
attr_accessible :lessonName, :subject, :subject_id
belongs_to :subject
```

Subject Controller

```
def new
3.times {@subject.lessons.build}
end

def create
  @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])
  if @subject.save
    redirect_to @subject, :notice => "Successfully created subject."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @subject do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :subjectCode %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :subjectCode %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :lessons do |builder| %>
    <p>    
    <%= builder.label :lessonName %> <br/>
    <%= builder.text_area :lessonName, :rows=>3 %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Routes
    resources :subjects do resources :lessons end

Comment: You are getting any error our it is just saving the `lesson` without the `subject_id`? Also, you should add `:lessons` inside your `attr_accessible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reject_if` lambda will always reject the lessons attributes because lessons don't have a `content` attribute, so you're essentially evaluating `nil.blank?` which will return `true`

Perhaps you want to check if the lesson name is blank? Ala `:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:lessonName].blank? }`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a field for `content` of lesson on form, so `content` will be blank with every lesson. And you also use:

```
:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

This will check if content is blank, the subject will not save the lesson. This is your problem, because you **don't have a content field on your form**, so **content will blank every time you create subject**, you used `:reject_if` so subject **will not save its lesson**. If you wan user can put content of lesson later, remove `:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true`  and your lesson will be save with associated subject.